# How do I use makefile to test my shell implementation?

Tags: c, shell, testing, makefile

Here is my current makefile, which does not run test correctly:

```
shell2: shell2.o
shell2.o: shell2.c

clean:    
        rm -f *.o 

test: shell2
        ./shell2 
        pwd 
        ./shell2
        cd ..
        ./shell2
        jobs
        ./shell2
        sleep 100 &
        jobs
        ./shell2
        exit
```

My program tests for newline to know when a command has been entered. This is the output of my 
program when I compile it myself manually:

```
$ pwd
/students/8/[redacted]/[redacted]/Shell2
$ cd ..
$ jobs
Jobs:
$ sleep 1000 &
To the background: 20203
$ jobs
Jobs:
20203
$ jobs
Jobs:
20203
$ killall sleep
sleep(17014): Operation not permitted
sleep(17305): Operation not permitted
sleep(17433): Operation not permitted
sleep(19741): Operation not permitted
sleep(19841): Operation not permitted
sleep(20041): Operation not permitted
sleep(20183): Operation not permitted
$ jobs
Jobs:
$ exit
now exiting...
```

Here is the output when I run make test:

```
make test
./shell2 
$ pwd
/students/8/[redacted]/[redacted]/Shell2
./shell2
$ cd ..
./shell2
$ jobs
make: jobs: Command not found
make: *** [test] Error 127
```

Also, I have to hit ctrl+D every time for a new line to execute during make test.

I'm trying to write this makefile for my class so that I can submit my assignment, my professor did not explain at all how to use a makefile besides the basic 
./a.out [input command]

He never explained how to use a makefile in the case that your program is running on a continuous loop like a shell is, waiting for the user to press [enter] or new line for the command to be parsed.

I checked the GNU man for make but it didn't explain much in the "testing" section.

Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.

**test_input.txt's output:**

```
./shell2 < test_input.txt
"Sending command: pwd"
/students/8/[redacted]/[redacted]/Shell2
"Sending command: cd .."
"Sending command: pwd"
/students/8/[redacted]/[redacted]
"Sending command: jobs"
$ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ Jobs:
$ 
"Sending command: sleep 1000 &"
$ $ To the background: 27199
"jobs"
$ $ Jobs:
27199
$ 
"Sending command: killall sleep"
$ $ $ $ Jobs:
"Sending command: jobs"
$ $ now exiting...
"exit"
```

**test_input.txt:**

```
echo "Sending command: pwd"
pwd
echo "Sending command: cd .."
cd ..
echo "Sending command: pwd"
pwd
echo "Sending command: jobs"
jobs

echo "Sending command: sleep 1000 &"
sleep 1000 &
echo "jobs"
jobs

echo "Sending command: killall sleep"
killall sleep
echo "Sending command: jobs"
jobs
echo "exit"
exit
```

Comment: post your code so we can test it -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to supply input to your program. You can't do this with make (directly) as make simply executes each line with `/bin/sh -c COMMAND`.

What you can do is

```
test: shell2
    ./shell2 < test_input.txt
```

to redirect input to the file `test_input.txt`, which would contain the commands you want.

Comment: ah ok, I'm getting closer now, thanks a lot. My test_input.txt file has been uploaded: for some reason I'm not getting the same output as if I were to just do it manually. Output from test_input.txt is now posted above along with test_input.txt itself.

Comment: Upon further inspection, I've noticed that the commands go to the shell and executes properly, but the output is still a little bonkers with the "$" character which is only supposed to appear once every new line.(it works properly when I manually test the program). The test input also doesn't show the input that it's providing to the shell so I've manually echo'd each command due to not knowing a better solution.

Comment: @HarrisonNguyen It seems your original question has been answered; accept the answer, then ask a new question if you want (though it seems you can handle it yourself).